# Android animation behind other views

Tags: android, animation

Developing for android I need a translate animation. That was easy, but I want the animation to go behind the other views. How can I achieve that? 
`setZAdjustment(Animation.ZORDER_BOTTOM)` does not work. It cannot be that hard...

Comment: please post your java and layout codes. This will make things easier

Comment: It is just a normal translation animation, but when it moves, it goes over the rest of views. How can I make it go under them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem in a RelativeLayout with an animated ImageView.

Defining/adding my animated View in the first place in/to the RelativeLayout and then the other views helped me.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this problem was to implement my own android.view.animation.Animation class, and overrride the applyTransformation() method. From this method I set a few of my own custom drawing variables, (X offset, etc.) and then called invalidate() on the view being animated. Note that my view as a custom view and I had all my drawing done in onDraw.