# LinearLayout Animation behind other views

Tags: android, animation

I'm currently programming an application in android, but I have a problem with animations. To simplicate, I have three "object" in a horizontal linear layout (2 buttons at the extremities, and a vertical linear layout in the center which I want to animate). The problem is that when I try to move it to the left, it pass over the button (and I want it behind). When I try to move it to the right, it pass behind the button (like I want).

In this topic it's also the same problem I think but there is no answer :( [Android animation behind other views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181948/android-animation-behind-other-views)

I have already tried `setZAdjustment(Animation.ZORDER_BOTTOM)` with my animations but it doesn't change anything.

Any idea ?

My Java code is quite simple :

```
layout_main= (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
moveNext= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.move_next_seq);
moveNext.setZAdjustment(Animation.ZORDER_BOTTOM);
layout_main.startAnimation(moveNext);
```

And my xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_previous"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/next_previous_button_width"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/button_classic"
    android:contentDescription="@string/button_previous_description"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

```
</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_next"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/next_previous_button_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/button_classic"
    android:contentDescription="@string/button_next_description"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />
```

and my animation :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

<set>
    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:startOffset="300"
        android:toXDelta="-100%" />
    <translate
        android:duration="1"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:startOffset="600"
        android:toXDelta="100%" />
    <translate
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:startOffset="601"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />
</set>
```